# How to publish a web API project under an existing application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am in the unfortunate situation where I have file access to a web server, but not administrative access.  There are a few aspx files currently, but nothing exceptionally dynamic.

What I'd like to do is publish a web API application - a separate 'project' - to a sub-directory of this server.

So I've got access to http://server/* via file and I want to set up http://server/MYAPP/api/Stuff

What's the best approach to doing this?

I only have file access and do not have an existing Visual Studio project for the website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Web API to existing asp.net web forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538119/adding-web-api-to-existing-asp-net-web-forms-application)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have an existing application project in VS.  I'm working with files.

Comment: If you don't have admin access, you can't create a new application under the existing web site in IIS. This means your web API project has to live in the root of the site (which already is an application). Just copy your assembly into the existing bin directory.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to go about this?  For example, can the bin files be segregated?  I can't take up the entire application website for this one thing.